# Short question about continuity of derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f_x:=\partial f/\partial x$ and $f_{xy}:=\partial f_x/\partial y$ exist, and $f_{xy}$ is continuous, does this imply that $f_x$ is also continuous?

I'm not sure if existence and continuity of one of the second partial derivatives imply the continuity first order partial derivative. Thanks.

Comment: $f(x,y)=\lvert x\rvert +xy$, has $f_{xy}$ with perhaps a removable discontinuity, but $f_x$ discontinuous.

Comment: So the answer is $f_{x}$ is not continuous in this case?

Comment: Yes. $f_x$ is discontinuous, but $f_{xy}$ appears to be continuous. Though it probably is not

Answer (score 0):

The existence and continuity of the second partial derivative (f_{xy}) does not necessarily imply the continuity of the first order partial derivative (f_x).

This is due to the fact that the continuity of a derivative at a point does not guarantee the continuity of the original function at that point. In other words, a function can have a derivative at a point without being continuous at that point.

However, if we know that all second order partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of the point in question (i.e., the function (f) is of class (C^2)), then by Clairaut's theorem, the mixed partial derivatives are equal, i.e., (f_{xy} = f_{yx}), and the first order partial derivatives (f_x) and (f_y) are also continuous.

So, in summary, the continuity of (f_{xy}) alone does not guarantee the continuity of (f_x), but if all second order partial derivatives are continuous, then (f_x) is also continuous.